# If a Postgres DB has unique IDs across its tables, how do you find a row using its ID without knowing its table?

Tags: postgresql

Following the [blog of Rob Conery](http://rob.conery.io/2014/05/29/a-better-id-generator-for-postgresql/) I have set of unique IDs across the tables of my Postgres DB.

Now, using these unique IDs, is there a way to query a row on the DB without knowing what table it is in? Or can those tables be indexed such that if the row is not available on the current table, I just increase the index and I can query to the next table?

Comment: Can the DB tables be accessed using table number since in select the selected column can be accessed using number?

Comment: The blog is actually about distributed database(s) collecting input. The UUID/GUID s are intended to make the *surrogate* keys (globally) unique. they typcally contain information (ie MAC-addres) about the place where they were generated ,and some timestamp/serial: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/uuid-ossp.htmlhttps://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/uuid-ossp.html

Comment: Your link is broken.

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/uuid-ossp.html

Answer (score 1):

In short - if you did not prepared for that - then no. You can prepare for that by generating your own uuid. Please look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1709600/what-kind-of-data-can-you-extract-from-a-uuid). For instance PG has uuid that preserve order. Also [uuid v5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10867405/generating-v5-uuid-what-is-name-and-namespace) has something like namespaces. So you can build hierarchy. However that is done by hashing namespace, and I don't know tool to do opposite inside PG.

Answer (score 0):

If you know all possible tables in advance you could prepare a query that simply `UNION`s a search with a tagged type over all tables. In case of two tables named `comments` and `news` you could do something like:

```
PREPARE type_of_id(uuid) AS
  SELECT id, 'comments' AS type
  FROM comments
  WHERE id = $1
  UNION
  SELECT id, 'news' AS type
  FROM news
  WHERE id = $1;

EXECUTE type_of_id('8ecf6bb1-02d1-4c04-8875-f1da62b7f720');
```

Automatically generating this could probably be done by querying `pg_catalog.pg_tables` and generating the relevant query on the fly.